# Did Nathan Bedford Forrest wear a wig or dye his hair?

Tags: united-states, racism, individuals

I have seen pictures of Nathan Bedford Forrest with a dark beard and light hair on his head.  Given that his head hair color does not match his beard color, did he wear a wig or dye his hair?  I have searched around for dyeing hair, and it seems he did not live to see the day when this was practical.  I have read about him, but I have not read he had a wig.  It seems that he had a receding hair line.  The black-and-white photos show a stark difference in his beard color and hair-on-his-head color.  Given that he was the first Grand Wizard of the KKK, it seems like he would have liked lighter hair color.  Here is an [illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_Bedford_Forrest#/media/File:Nathan_B._Forrest_-_LOCc.jpg) of the different head hair and beard hair color.
[image: N.B. Forrest with dark beard and lighter hair]

Comment: Is it relly unusual for a man's beard to be darker, or to remain dark longer, than the hair on his head? How have you researched this?

Comment: "Given that he was the first Grand Wizard of the KKK, it seems like he would have liked lighter hair color" seems a total *non sequitur*. Can you explain why you think the one thing would follow from the other?

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.djournal.com/news/auction-sells-history/article_0bfe4642-6931-5ffb-9c68-308e992c24a2.html), Forrest owned an item of furniture called a (rosewood) wig dresser. I'm not sure that a wig dresser is as its name seems to suggest, or whether it was for him or perhaps his wife, but maybe someone can investigate further.

Comment: It's not uncommon for the goatee portion of the beard to go grey more slowly than the rest.  Possibly that's why, at least in that picture, he shaved the rest of it...

Comment: My beard is much darker than my hair as a matter of fact (well, it used to be. Now it has rather a lot of gray in it...)

Comment: @RichardJ  surprisingly interesting question.  Thank you for asking it.   I enjoyed looking into it and actually turned my initial thinking around.  Nice job.

Comment: i have dirty blonde hair but a dark brown almost black beard and my cousin has blonde hair and a reddish beard, so i guess its just genetics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:**
Did Nathan Bedford Forrest wear a wig or dye his hair?

**Short Answer:**
No wig, but more evidence than one might think suggests Forrest did dye his hair, probably with some sort of natural product, tree bark or herb product.

1. Forrest was the right age to need the use of such a product.
2. Hair dye products were commercially available before and during the Civil War.
3. Evidence suggests dye was used by Civil War soldiers when sitting for photographs in the same theatre of the war where Forrest saw action.
4. The photograph you reference suggests dye was present.

**Detailed Answer:**

He didn't use synthetic hair dyes.  The first synthetic dyes were created in the UK in 1863 by English chemist **[William Henry Perkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Henry_Perkin)**.  Commercial products for these dyes were not available until 1907 when **[Eugene Schueller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eug%C3%A8ne_Schueller)** the founder of L'Oreal first introduced a synthetic hair dye product.  So If Forrest was dying his hair he was using a natural mixture of plants and nuts which have been used to color hair dating back to Egyptian and Roman days.

**Suggestive evidence** that Forrest dyed his hair:

1. Forrest was born July 13, 1821  so he was 40 years old when the Civil War began.
   Modern men begin to turn grey as early as the [age of 30](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/why-am-i-going-gray_n_562900c8e4b0aac0b8fbdb3b#:%7E:text=%22On%20average%2C%2050%20percent%20of,hairs%20around%2035%2C%20Schweiger%20notes.).  So if Forrest was vain enough to care, he could have had the motivation.
2. Natural non synthetic hair dye was commercially available during the Civil War.

> New York c.1850 Hair Dye - [Cristadoro](http://www.bottleland.com/idM34.htm)
> [image: Bottle]

> **[Dr. D. Jayne's Liquid Hair Dye](http://www.hairraisingstories.com/Products/JAYNE_LHD.html)**
> Dr. David Jayne and Sons were selling this preparation from around 1857 until the mid-1860s.
> [image: four bottles]

3. During the Civil War there is research suggesting men sitting for photographs often for the first time, used hair dye.  The evidence pertains to soldiers in Kentucky the same theatre as General Forrest fought, only on the Union side rather than Forrest's Confederate side.

[Civil War Soldiers Used Hair Dye to Make Themselves Look Better in Pictures, Archaeologists Discover](https://www.newsweek.com/civil-war-soldiers-hair-dye-pictures-archaeologists-1476195)

4. Men's beards typically grey first not their scalp hair as the picture in question clearly shows.  This possibly suggests dye was used.

> **[Why Do Beards Turn Grey First?](https://kingsoftoday.com/why-do-beards-turn-grey-first/#:%7E:text=As%20you%20age%2C%20the%20follicles,and%20then%20on%20their%20heads.)**
> Greying is the result of a depletion of melanin in your hair follicles. As you age, the follicles produce less melanin, which causes either grey, silver, or white hair. Beard hair grows faster than hair on your head. This is why most people notice the depletion of melanin (or greying) in their beards first and then on their heads.

also

British Journal of Dermatology  **[Greying of the human hair: a worldwide survey, revisiting the ‘50’ rule of thumb](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1365-2133.2012.11095.x)**

Comment: This is enough convince me that it is technically and culturally possible that Forest might have dyed his hair, so you have my upvote for that. But I wouldn't call that evidence that he actually *did* so, as you claim. Also, if I'm reading this right, you are you suggesting that he may have dyed his beard because it was grey first? But why would he choose to dye his beard only and leave his hair grey.

Comment: @BrianZ,  as I said.. The evidence is suggestive and not definitive.   Personally I was surprised I found so much suggestive evidence.  Thank you for the question it was fun going back and forth on it with myself.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen no clear evidence either way, but the following anecdote from *Nathan Bedford Forrest: A Biography* by Jack Hurst may be of interest.

> At a dinner during the war, to a society woman who inquired why his hair had turned gray while his beard remained dark, he replied that it was possibly because he tended to work his brains more than his jaws.

Comment: when I was a child my grandfather was bald.   I always asked, "why are you bald?"  He would say, "grass doesn't grow on a busy street".   My mom cut in, "it doesn't grow on granite either".